# DigitSum method in Java

Tags: java, debugging, variables, methods, parameters

Trying to follow the "Art and science of Java" book I am doing some exercise programs. This program is intended to read in integer `n` and return the number of digits

```java
import acm.program.*;

public class DigitSum extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        println("This program tells you how many digits is in a number");
        int n = readInt("Enter the number which you want to check: ");
        int dSum =0;
        println("The number of digits is: "+myMethod(n,dSum));
    }
    private int myMethod (int n, int dSum) {
        while (n>0) {
            dSum += n%10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return dSum;

    }

}
```

Can someone tell me why my program is not working as intended? If I run it and set `n` to 555 it says that the number of digits is 15 which is clearly not correct.

Comment: this program writes the sum of digits and not the number of digits

Comment: Omg, I am sorry. Was re-writing a program that wrote the sum in the run method into one that wrote the number in a seperate method. Guess i didn't do that job well :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding 5+5+5 i.e. 15.

If you want number of digit then you will need to use counter.

```
private int myMethod (int n, int dSum) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (n>0) {
        dSum += n%10;
        n /= 10;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;

}
```

Comment: Omg, I am sorry. Was re-writing a program that wrote the sum in the run method into one that wrote the number in a seperate method. Guess i didn't do that job well :D

Comment: Btw, no need to pass `dSum` as method variable, you can create it inside your method.